# Get calendar events from SQL/PHP to Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, calendar

I have an existing calendar code below:

```
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div id="calendar"></div>
    </div>  
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({ header: { left: 'prev,next today', center: 'title', right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay' }, eventLimit: true, events: [
            {
                title: 'Test Job',
                start: '2016-03-09'
            }
        ]
        }); 
        }); 
    </script>
```

Now what I want to do is to fetch the values of title and start from records in the database, based on specific columns. I tried to do below, which echoes javascript from php, but it doesn't display anything. What it aims to do is to iterate through all the records in the database and generate the fragment in the javascript that creates an event, but it is inside php. Could you enlighten me out on possible solutions for this implementation? Thanks!

```
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
        echo '$(function(){';
        echo "$('#calendar').fullCalendar({ header: { left: 'prev,next today', center: 'title', right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay' }, eventLimit: true, events: [";
        $query = "SELECT * FROM data WHERE date >= DATE(NOW());";
        $exec = mysql_query($query,$conn);
        while ($row = $result = mysql_fetch_array($exec))
        {
            $result2--;
            echo "{title: '";
            echo $row["title"] . "',";
            echo "start: '" . $row["date"] . "'";
            echo "}";
            if ($result2<=1)
                echo ",";

        }           
        echo "]";
        echo "}); }); ";
        echo "</script>";
```

Comment: It's difficult to tell based on the code alone, can you provide a reproducible example of the problem in a JS Fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

@Lane What you will want to do it use javascript AJAX to call the server; the server then processes the request and returns the requested data. On successful return javascript alters the HTML to display the new data.

https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/ is a decent start playing with javascript AJAX.
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_connect.asp basic PHP + MySQL examples.

Post script: Please do not use echo in multiple lines to print out JS script. `echo` supports line breaks.